# How can I run specific project?

Tags: ionic-framework

All !!
I have two projects - 1st project and 2nd project.

At the 1st project directory, I can run project with below command.

> ionic serve

At the 2nd project directory, I can't run project with same command. Only run 1st project.

But, after 1st project run, and then run "ionic serve", I can run 2nd project successfully.

How can I run 2nd project without 1st project run?

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwsKv.png)

Answer (score 0):

It solved!
I missed add platform.

> ionic cordova platform add android

After that, when i into specitic direcotry, i can run only that project. :)

Thank you for all!